# How to figure out the schematic inside a "black box" if the only information I have is the signal equation: U(t) and I(t)

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, analog

Professor gave us a problem and I can't seem to figure it out. The task seems quite simple: we have a black box that has some kind of RLC circuit inside it, one input wire and one output wire connected to AC.
He gave us two equations:
$$
u(t)=2\cdot \sin(\omega t+\pi/4)
$$
and:
$$
i(t)=\sin(\omega t+75^\circ)
$$
Using the information given I need to figure out what the circuit inside the black box is.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Explain exactly what u(t) and i(t) represent with respect to the black box. Also are you given the value of w? Is there a common wire between the input and output?

Comment: @Barry u(t) and i(t) are the equations that describe the signal wave that goes through the circuit, the voltage and current correspondingly. W is W, it's a known variable. The output and the input are connected through a voltage/current source, like two wires connected to a wall socket.

Comment: w probably is supposed to be a lower-case omega, representing 2 x pi x the input AC frequency.

Comment: I'm confused. Even after these comments. So I'll sit back and see how things play out.

Comment: @hakkulinen I edited your question to format the equations. You can click on edit to see how the formatting is done. It's similar to LaTeX, double dollar sign before and after equations that are set apart from the text or to inline an equation in the text use backslash and dollar sign. I assumed w means lowercase omega.

Comment: You can't know exactly what the circuit is, as there are infinitely many possible equivalent circuits. But you can find a maximally reduced form (of which there may still be a handful of possible equivalents, for sufficiently complex circuits). As you have information only at one frequency, I *think* the maximally reduced form will be a single resistor in series with a single inductor or capacitor (or just one of those components, if purely resistive or reactive).

Comment: I assume by "one input wire and one output wire" you mean a single two-terminal port, and you are not talking about a two-port network? You don't normally talk about *single* wires as "inputs" or "outputs" in this sort of context--the words "input" or "output" refer to *ports*, which are pairs of wires.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, apologies for my terminology, I'm studying electrical engineering in a different language, so it gets a bit hazy when I try to explain what I mean :D Indeed those are simple wires, I just assumed that the wire entering the box could be considered an "input". It's definitely not one, it's just a wire of a contour, right. I do in fact have info only for a single frequency, and I have a feeling the professor expects us to solve this through a mix of phasial diagrams and complex amplitudes, since that's what we've learned recently... But I'm still not sure how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Any help will be appreciated!*

I would start by using the formulas to calculate impedance and convert them to simple polar values. For instance, the voltage across the two terminals written as \$2\sin(wt+π/4)\$ converts to a polar format of \$1.4142 \angle 45\$. And the current converts to \$0.7071\angle 75\$. The impedance is therefore: -

$$2\dfrac{\angle 45}{\angle 75}\hspace{1cm} = \hspace{1cm} 2\angle-30\hspace{1cm} = \hspace{1cm} 1.7321 - j1$$

So, you have a 2 ohm impedance that is capacitive with a series resistance like this: -

[image]

Image from [Series Resistor-Capacitor Circuits](https://ecstudiosystems.com/discover/textbooks/lessons/AC/chapter4-3-series-resistor-capacitor-circuits/)

However, given that you haven't stated the angular frequency it's impossible to drill down more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have another question, is it okay if I explain the capacitiveness of my impedance through the logic that since the phase angle of my current(t) is greater than the phase angle of my voltage(t), I can say that my current outruns my voltage and (since the professor considers this to be common knowledge, apparently) this happens exactly when it's capacitive. The angular frequency is sort of given, we know it to be omega, it's a known, but numerically unstated value (probably because the professor considers it irrelevant to the solution)

Comment: I wouldn't describe it that way @hakkulinen Something that outruns something else implies two things that are moving apart and clearly, the phase angles are constant. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: I don't exactly understand on what logic you base the conclusion that this impedance is capacitive... Also by "outruns" I meant that when we graph it, i(t) will overtake u(t) in phase, it will osscilate "faster". Well, the sine wave will

Comment: I'm sorry but your choice of words for describing the action of a capacitive load are faulty. If you don't understand what sort of impedance can represent a capacitor mathematically, I suggest you do some background research. Neither does "oscillate faster" provide anything like a satisfactory explanation.

Comment: @hakkulinen, I believe what Andy means is that the current leads the voltage by 90 degrees in a purely capacitive circuit.

Comment: @DimitarZhekov I do not subscribe precisely to that explanation either.

Comment: @Andyaka what will be a clearer explanation?

Comment: Maybe describe it somewhat how Dimitar states it using the word "leading" i.e. the phase angle of the current leads the phase angle of the voltage?